# Load FileName in SQL Table using Copy Data Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am newbie to Azure Data Factory. I'm trying to load multiple files of various states from FTP location into a single Azure SQL Server table. My requirement is to get state name from of the file and dump it into table along with actual data.

Currently, my source is FTP. Sink is Azure SQL Server table. I have used Stored Procedure to load the data. However, I'm unable to send file name as a parameter as shown below to the stored procedure so that I can dump it into the table.   Below is the Copy Data component -

[image]

I have defined SourceFileName parameter in stored procedure, however, I am unable to send it via COPY Data activity.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that the  state name is from the file name？

Comment: I remember  that in the source of the copy activity, there is an **additional column** option, you can get the filename via `$$filename`

Comment: Yes @JosephXu - the name of the file has state name like sample_CA (California) etc

Comment: Yes, I saw that $$filename variable of Source part and tried to put it in Value ($$filename) of param as highlighted in yellow in above screenshot in Sink part. it throws an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can conclude that **additional column** option can not be used here. Because ADF will return a column(contain filepath) not a string. So we need to use GetMetaData activity to get the file list, then foreach the file list  and inside a Foreach activity to copy them.

I've created a simple test, it works well.

1. In my local FTP server, there is two text files. I need to copy them into an Azure SQL table.
   [image]
2. At GetMetaData activity, I use `Child Items` to get the filelist.
   [image]
3. At ForEach activity, I use `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems` to foreach the file list.
   [image]
4. Inside the ForEach activity, I use dynamic content `@item().name` to get the file path.
   **source setting:**
   [image]
   **sink setting:**
   [image]
5. So we can get the filename. Follows are some operations I did on Azure SQL.

   ```sql
   -- create a table
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[employee](
       [firstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
       [lastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
       [filePath] [varchar](50) NULL
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
   GO

   -- create a table type
   CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ct_employees_type] AS TABLE(
       [firstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
       [lastName] [varchar](50) NULL
   )
   GO

   -- create a Stored procedure
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO

   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO

   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpsertEmployees]

   @employees ct_employees_type READONLY,
   @filePath varchar(50)

   AS

   BEGIN
   set @filePath = SUBSTRING( @filePath,1,len(@filePath)-4)

   MERGE [dbo].[employee] AS target_sqldb

   USING @employees AS source_tblstg

   ON (target_sqldb.firstName = source_tblstg.firstName)

   WHEN MATCHED THEN

   UPDATE SET

   firstName = source_tblstg.firstName,

   lastName = source_tblstg.lastName


   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN

   INSERT (

       firstName,

       lastName,

       filePath

   )

   VALUES (

       source_tblstg.firstName,

       source_tblstg.lastName,

       @filePath
   );

   END
   GO
   ```
6. After I run debug, the result is follows:
   [image]